# How do you work with database meta key and values?

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m trying to use SQL to retrieve Woocommerce order item meta keys and values so that I can summarise the information in my own report, but I am really struggling to extract meta keys and values as columns. Could anyone provide any SQL examples? Is there a Wordpress API I can use for metadata?

I have tried creating the following SQL as a basis for extending the query for product information. It returns the right kind of data but only a single row:

```
SELECT O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name,
    MAX(IF(OIM.meta_key = 'class', OIM.meta_value, NULL)) AS class
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items AS O
LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS OIM on O.order_item_id = 
OIM.order_item_id
WHERE O.order_item_name='Smiths Night School';
```

Thanks

Comment: There is a cool search console named Google which returns you an array with > 440.000 entries when you search for this topic. ;)

Comment: Thanks for that incredibly unhelpful response. I have Googled the topic extensively and asked for help on forums without any answer.

Comment: Have you checked WooCommerce's documentation already? There must be a function for this already.

Comment: Because these are basics of WordPress development mate. For example when I search for: WordPress select from database: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb. So this is the basic thing. WooCommerce implemented this for you so you can use functions to get order item values by keys. (see the documentation or search on SO): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)

Comment: You've posted your select. Can you please also post the way you trying to execute the select?

Comment: Thanks for your response. At the moment, I'm trying to execute the select just from the phpmyadmin console to make sure it returns the correct results before I execute it from code.

Comment: How much items do you have with "Smiths Night School"?

Comment: It has many items. I've posted the answer but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad that you got it! This is the best way to learn things. To help you a bit, I'll show you the correct way to do this in WordPress (PHP):

```
<?php

//DB
global $wpdb; 

//Get results from the database
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name, MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'class' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'class', MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'fee-type' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'fees' FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items O INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta OIM ON O.order_item_id = OIM.order_item_id WHERE O.order_item_name='Smiths Night School' GROUP BY O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name" );

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    echo $result->your_field_from_the_table;
}
```

WordPress defines a class called `wpdb`, which contains a set of functions used to interact with a database. It's a good way using this class, because it's simple and save.

You also don't need to define your `password` and `user` of the database within any PHP file (What you need to do if you use the PHP database functionality). If you use `wpdb`, this information comes directly out of the `wp-config.php` file which is a bit more safe.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works well. This query returns class and fee-type information for every order_item_name of "Smiths Night School".

```
SELECT 
  O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'class' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'class',
  MAX(CASE WHEN OIM.meta_key = 'fee-type' THEN OIM.meta_value END) AS 'fees'
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items O
INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta OIM ON O.order_item_id = OIM.order_item_id
WHERE O.order_item_name='Smiths Night School'
GROUP BY O.order_item_id, O.order_item_name
```

Comment: If you want to do this now in WordPress, you can check my answer.